# Limit user to one marker on map

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm using Google Maps V2 API in my Android app. I have included a method that allows the user to place a marker, which is draggable, with onMapLongClick. I am also planning on including functionality to tie it in with the SearchView widget and Google Places. In that regard, I want to limit the user to having the ability to place only one marker on the map. If they invoke either method to place a marker a second time, I want the existing marker to update its position to the new input. I've been researching this for a few days and haven't been able to turn anything up regarding limiting the number of markers a user can place to 1. Any ideas on how to accomplish this? Here is the method I am using now...

```
//onMapLongClick, create marker
@Override    
public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(point)
    .title("Your Destination")           
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher))
    .draggable(true));
}
```

Comment: It's very easy. like first user add one Marker in `onMapClick()` now, if user `onMapclick()` again then update your older point to the newer point

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I haven't worked with maps in android, but try something like this, just giving an idea

```
Marker m; //reference to the marker 

   //onMapLongClick, if marker exists update its position, else create marker
@Override
public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
  if (m) { //if marker exists (not null or whatever)
    m.setPosition(point);
  } else {
    m = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(point)
        .title("Your Destination")
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher))
        .draggable(true));
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow! You've really gone above and beyond with this answer. I am going to vote +1 for the thoroughness, and I will follow up with you once I have tried it out. I could use "point" as a field that is updated with LatLng from either the user's onMapLongClick, or from Google Places, correct?

Comment: That worked famously! Woot! Thank you for that, and for making me feel a bit dumber for not being able to come up with that on my own. I will sit here quietly and sip my scotch.